# creating a new empty data frame in each loop?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a new data frame for each one of my loops in a for loop; but i can't seem to get a new data frame each time.

```
for(j in 1:10){
    df_j = data.frame()
}
```

What I am trying to get is a bunch of new data frames in my environment.

df_1
df_2
df_3
df_4
df_5
df_6
df_7
df_8
df_9
df_10

Im quite new to coding, so any help will be appreciated, thanks.

When i tryied this it just made one data frame called 'df_j'.

Answer (score 4):

Creating new variables in a loop / automatically isn't a good idea. Consider using a *list* instead:

- Outside the `for` loop create `my_list <- list()`.
- Inside your loop assign the new data.frames using `my_list[[j]] <- data.frame()`.
- Access a data.frame for example via `my_list[[5]]` which is more or less your intended `df_5`.

```
my_list <- list()

for(j in 1:10){
  my_list[[j]] <- data.frame()
}

my_list[[5]]
```

Comment: Also see @GregorThomas’s [classic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/17303805) on why a list of dataframes is usually preferable to a bunch of dataframes loose in the environment.